# apt-get or aptitude

Tags: aptitude, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the real difference between “apt-get” and “aptitude”?  (How about “wajig”?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767/what-is-the-real-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude-how-about-wajig)

I'm new in Linux (Ubuntu) world. When I need to install something I Google for it and frequently I found some command like apt-get install [package name]

My friend told me that aptitude provides more functionality and it's better to use it instead.

But as I know aptitude will be removed from next version of Ubuntu (yes, it will be possible to install it, but it will be excluded by default).

What better to use: apt-get or aptitude?