# What is the real difference between "apt-get" and "aptitude"? (How about "wajig"?)

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, aptitude

I know that both `apt-get` and `aptitude` are command line package management interfaces on Debian derived Linux, with different options, but I'm still somewhat confused.  Under the hood, aren't they using the same APT system?

Why does Debian maintain these parallel tools?  (Bonus question: what on earth is [wajig](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/wajig.1.html)?)

Comment: I know its not the correct answerer for you question but why cant you try synaptic? its very user frindly and does download and install dependencies automatically.  
Is gnome is not present on your system?

Comment: I'm biased, but I think [this question on the Ubuntu SE site](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/76/whats-the-difference-between-ubuntus-package-managers) might be relevant.

Comment: duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244/apt-get-or-aptitude .

Comment: @Wim because of the wajig portion of this question I decided to merge 244 into this question instead of the other way around

Comment: Its worth noting that aptitude is slated for removal from the default install on the next version of Ubuntu (although you could always install it using apt-get afterwards)

Comment: `apt-get` is now apt

Comment: @WimCoenen your duplicate link lead back here lol

Answer (score 243, accepted):

The most obvious difference is that `aptitude` provides a terminal menu interface (much like Synaptic in a terminal), whereas `apt-get` does not.

Considering only the command-line interfaces of each, they are quite similar, and for the most part, it really doesn't matter which one you use. Recent versions of both will track which packages were manually installed, and which were installed as dependencies (and therefore eligible for automatic removal). In fact, I believe that even more recently, the two tools were updated to actually share the same database of manually vs automatically installed packages, so cases where you install something with apt-get and then aptitude wants to uninstall it are mostly a thing of the past.

There are a few minor differences:

- aptitude will automatically remove eligible packages, whereas apt-get requires a separate command to do so
- The commands for *upgrade* vs. *dist-upgrade* have been renamed in aptitude to the probably more accurate names *safe-upgrade* and *full-upgrade*, respectively.
- aptitude actually performs the functions of not just apt-get, but also some of its companion tools, such as apt-cache and apt-mark.
- aptitude has a slightly different query syntax for searching (compared to apt-cache)
- aptitude has the *why* and *why-not* commands to tell you which *manually installed* packages are preventing an action that you might want to take.
- If the actions (installing, removing, updating packages) that you want to take cause conflicts, aptitude can suggest several potential resolutions. apt-get will just say "I'm sorry Dave, I can't allow you to do that."

There are other small differences, but those are the most important ones that I can think of.

In short, aptitude more properly belongs in the category with Synaptic and other higher-level package manager frontends. It just happens to also have a command-line interface that resembles apt-get.

### Bonus Round: What is wajig?

Remember how I mentioned those "companion" tools like `apt-cache` and `apt-mark`? Well, there's a bunch of them, and if you use them a lot, you might not remember which ones provide which commands. `wajig` is one solution to that problem. It is essentially a dispatcher, a wrapper around all of those tools. It also applies `sudo` when necessary. When you say `wajig install foo`, wajig says "Ok, `install` is provided by `apt-get` and requires admin privileges," and it runs `sudo apt-get install foo`. When you say `wajig search foo`, wajig says "Ok, `search` is provided by `apt-cache` and does not require admin privileges," and it runs `apt-cache search foo`. If you use wajig instead of apt-get, apt-mark, apt-cache and others, then you'll never have this problem:

```
$ apt-get search foo
E: Invalid operation search
```

If you want to know what wajig is doing behind the scenes, which tools it is using to implement a particular command, it has `--simulate` and `--teaching` modes.

Two wajig commands that I often use are `wajig listfiles foo` and `wajig whichpkg /usr/bin/foo`.

Comment: One big issue I had with aptitude is that it takes a long time to get tab completions on package names (eg, `aptitude install linux-im` tab), while it is very fast for apt-get. There seems to be some caching present in the apt-get family that is lacking for aptitude.

Comment: `aptitude` also have the awesome `aptitude search` that you can use with ***very powerful [search patterns](http://algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html)***. You have `aptitude reinstall`. You can also use the ncurses (terminal menu) interface to *prepare complex package operations* like partial upgrade, remove one package, freeze another one, upgrade this one, that *you can then execute in a single operation*... Oh, and it has an *interactive conflict resolver*.

Comment: @Totor holy cow, using aptitude's ncurses interface to prepare commands just sold me on aptitude once and for all! (after years of thinking aptitude is worth doing, but typing apt-get from muscle memory)

Comment: ...and `aptitude` also has `aptitude download package-name` to get the package .deb file!

Comment: It's just one thing I have found that isn't in `aptitude` but are in `apt-get`, and that is `apt-get --compile source package-name`.  `apt-get build-dep package-name` exist but I think that `aptitude build-dep package-name` do a better job.

Comment: Dependency resolver in *aptitude* is great thing, but I remember, back when I used to use *testing*; especially right after release, it used to get stuck in endless loop or offer "solutions" like remove half of the system. **When that happens**: give good old `apt-get update` a shot.

Comment: Nice! I've solved some erlang install issues with aptitude self-solve!

Answer (score 78):

I've often wondered myself. [Wikipedia highlights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29) that the main distinguishing feature is that aptitude has a full screen text-mode (curses) interface. The fact that you can use most `apt-get` command arguments with `aptitude` itself is just a design decision to make it easier for `apt-get` users to move to `aptitude` and vice-versa.

I've never used `wajig`, but the documentation suggests that it's just a script which knows whether you're passing it a `deb` file (when it runs `dpkg`) or an `apt` package name (when it runs `apt-get` instead). Could you try it out and see if that is what it does?

Of course, the *real* difference is:

```
gaurav@fern:~$ apt-get moo
         (__) 
         (oo) 
   /------\/ 
  / |    ||   
 *  /\---/\ 
    ~~   ~~   
...."Have you mooed today?"...
gaurav@fern:~$ aptitude moo
There are no Easter Eggs in this program.
```

Comment: No! `aptitude` has more. You forgot to put the endless `-v` flags to `moo`. (You can go upto `-vvvvvv`)

Comment: Don't forget the all important Super Cow Powers, which `apt-get` has but `aptitude` does not. (Try `--help` on both)

Comment: lmao. that is a fun answer to read, even though @ryan's answer is far more elaborate ;)

Answer (score 29):

aptitude is the preferred program for package management from console both for package installations and package or system upgrades in Debian.

Here is an overview of the tool and the features it has over apt-get:
http://www.debian.org/doc/FAQ/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-aptitude

So, my advice is to just apt-get install aptitude :)

Comment: The [release notes](http://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/i386/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#upgradingpackages) say apt-get is now recommended over aptitude for upgrades to squeeze.

Comment: Yes, but only for that.  Otherwise they are considered equal but `aptitude` has a lot of more advanced features, like search and full screen mode, than `apt-get`.

Comment: For some reason used aptitude to install emacs and without looking it removed gdm! So for the now will be using apt-get but am very curious of aptitude.

Answer (score 25):

`aptitude` remembers which packages were explicitly requested and which were only installed due to dependencies. It will automatically uninstall packages which were not explicitly requested when they are no longer needed.

`apt-get` treats packages requested explicitly and their dependencies the same.

So better use `aptitude`, this helps to keep your system clean.

Comment: This used to be true, but I know my apt-get has an `apt-get autoremove` command for removing packages installed only as dependencies. I don't know when this feature was added, but one website suggests it might have happened with Debian Lenny (June 2010).

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` doesn't remove packages installed only as dependencies, it removes orphaned dependencies, which is a subtle difference; it can't tell whether a 'leaf' package was installed with intent or as a dependency so it leaves it, where aptitude would know and remove it.

Comment: I'm sold!  There are other nice things about `aptitude` but this is hands-down a killer feature.

Answer (score 16):

Building on @Gaurav's answer, the easter eggs in the two package managers are quite funny!:

```
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ apt-get  moo
             (__) 
             (oo) 
       /------\/ 
      / |    ||   
     *  /\---/\ 
        ~~   ~~   
..."Have you mooed today?"...

siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude  moo
There are no Easter Eggs in this program.
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -v moo
There really are no Easter Eggs in this program.
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vv moo
Didn't I already tell you that there are no Easter Eggs in this program?
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vvv moo
Stop it!
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vvvv moo
Okay, okay, if I give you an Easter Egg, will you go away?
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vvvvv moo
All right, you win.

                               /----\
                       -------/      \
                      /               \
                     /                |
   -----------------/                  --------\
   ----------------------------------------------
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vvvvvv moo
What is it?  It's an elephant being eaten by a snake, of course.
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vvvvvvv moo
What is it?  It's an elephant being eaten by a snake, of course.
siddhartha@siddhartha-dev:~$ aptitude -vvvvvvvv moo
What is it?  It's an elephant being eaten by a snake, of course.
```

and so on.

Answer (score 14):

`apt-get`, as well as the various companion tools, use significantly less memory than respective command-line invocations of `aptitude`, and are a bit quicker.  I was blissfully unaware of this until I tried upgrading the debian install on a wizened old pentium thinkpad with 32MB of ram.  It would take an hour or two of swap-thrashing to run `apt-get`, which completed successfully; `aptitude` would fail after I think a longer period of time.

This distinction is more or less irrelevant on anything resembling a modern desktop system.

Answer (score 9):

They offer the same basic functionality: install and remove packages from the command-line.

[Here's](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-really-better-than-apt-get/1749#1749) a more detailed comparison, posted on the [Ubuntu Stack Exchange website](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com): https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-really-better-than-apt-get/1749#1749

Comment: They are pretty similar, I can switch between them easy enough.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned be http://pthree.org/2007/08/12/aptitude-vs-apt-get/, `aptitude` has a much easier to use command-line interface.

> Under the hood, aren't they using the same APT system? 
>   Yes.

The underlying system is not just `apt`, but `dpkg`. This system is just as dumb as RPM, it can only handle the installation and administration of single packages. It tracks which installed files belong to which package.

`apt` handles the downloads of repositories, tracking of dependencies, and so on for all individual packages - which it then installs using `dpkg`. `aptitude` does the same, with a different interface.

Answer (score 8):

Both apt-get and aptitude rely on the APT library, yes.

See my [answer on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/21105/whats-the-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude/21505#21505).

Debian is not a monolithic entity, there are people with different opinions and the aptitude maintainer decided that apt-get had some shortcomings and wanted to build something better with aptitude. He improved the logic to find solutions for complex upgrade scenarios, added a GUI for the console, etc. And there's more than just apt-get and aptitude, see my article [apt-get, aptitude, … pick the right package manager for you](http://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/06/20/apt-get-aptitude-%e2%80%a6-pick-the-right-debian-package-manager-for-you/).

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this still holds but the bleeding edge Debian developer Joey Hess always used to advocate aptitude over apt-get. Of course things to change as software evolves. Apt-get now handles dependencies better than it used to. 
From http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2004/04/msg03138.html

Date: Tue, 20 Apr 2004 22:27:12 -0400
From: Joey Hess

Nine reasons why you should be using aptitude instead of apt-get or dselect.

1. aptitude can look just like apt-get

   If you run 'aptitude update' or 'aptitude upgrade' or 'aptitude
   install', it looks and works just like apt-get, with a few enhancements.
   So there is no learning curve.

   (If you're a dselect user, learning curve is obviously not one of your
   problems.)
2. aptitude tracks automatically installed packages

   Stop worrying about pruning unused libraries and support packages from
   your system. If you use aptitude to install everything, it will keep
   track of what packages are pulled in by dependencies alone, and remove
   those packages when they are no longer needed.
3. aptitude sanely handles recommends

   A long-standing failure of apt-get has been its lack of support for
   the Recommends relationship. Which is a problem because many packages
   in Debian rely on Recommends to pull in software that the average user
   generally uses with the package. This is a not uncommon cause of
   trouble, even though apt-get recently became able to at least mention
   recommended packages, it's easy to miss its warnings.

   Aptitude supports Recommends by default, and can be confgigured to
   support Suggests too. It even supports installing recommended packages
   when used in command-line mode.
4. use aptitude as a normal user and avoid hosing your system

   Maybe you didn't know that you can run aptitude in gui mode as a regular
   user. Make any changes you'd like to try out. If you get into a real
   mess, you can hit 'q' and exit, your changes will not be saved.
   (Aptitude also lets you use ctrl-u to undo changes.) Since it's running
   as a normal user, you cannot hose your system until you tell aptitude to
   do something, at which point it will prompt you for your root password.
5. aptitude has a powerful UI and searching capabilities

   Between aptitude's categorical browser and its great support for
   mutt-style filtering and searching of packages by name, description,
   maintainer, dependencies, etc, you should be able to find packages
   faster than ever before using aptitude.
6. aptitude makes it easy to keep track of obsolete software

   If Debian stops distributing a package, apt will leave it on your system
   indefinitly, with no warnings, and no upgrades. Aptitude lists such
   packages in its "Obsolete and Locally Created Packages" section, so you
   can be informed of the problem and do something about it.
7. aptitude has an interface to the Debian task system

   Aptitude lets you use Debian's task system as it was designed to be
   used. You can browse the available tasks, select a task for install, and
   then dig into it and de-select parts of the task that you don't want.
   apt-get has no support for tasks, and aptitude is better even than
   special purpose tools like tasksel.
8. aptitude supports multiple sources

   If your sources.list is configured to make multiple versions of a
   package available, aptitude lets you drill down to see the available
   versions and pick a non-default version to install. If a package breaks
   in unstable, just roll it back to the version in testing.
9. aptitude logs its actions

   Aptitude logs package it installs, upgrades, and removes to
   /varlog/aptitude, which can be useful to work out why things started
   breaking after yesterday's upgrade, or when you removed a partiticlar
   package.

-- 
see shy jo

===================
there is also a newer discussion from 2010 here https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use on StackExchange.