# `apt clean` vs `apt-get clean`

Tags: linux, command-line, apt, package-management, aptitude

Are these `apt` commands identical to their `apt-get` counterparts / namesakes?

---

- `apt clean`
  `apt-get clean`
- `apt autoclean`
  `apt-get autoclean`
- `apt autoremove`
  `apt-get autoremove`

  ---

They do appear to be.  Just wanting to confirm.

Comment: see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767/what-is-the-real-difference-between-apt-get-and-aptitude-how-about-wajig and http://www.tecmint.com/difference-between-apt-and-aptitude/

Answer (score 4):

From `man apt`:

> DIFFERENCES TO APT-GET(8)
>          The apt command is meant to be pleasant for end users and does not need to be backward compatible like apt-get(8). Therefore some
>   options are different:
>
> ```
>    ·   The option DPkgPM::Progress-Fancy is enabled.
>
>    ·   The option APT::Color is enabled.
>
>    ·   A new list command is available similar to dpkg --list.
>
>    ·   The option upgrade has --with-new-pkgs enabled by default.
> ```